# Anyone recognize this software/web interface?

Tags: user-interface, web, interface, software-design

Saw this picture of some kind of web interface. Was wondering if anyone could recognize it and may have a name for it?

[Software/Web Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsyj4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a the Neo4J UI https://neo4j.com - is a graph database management system
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrnI6.png)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Neo4j instance - it's a graph database. Beyond that, I'm not sure what you are asking.